# Retrieving past application specific passwords

Tags: google, security, passwords

I'm curious if there is a way to view past application specific passwords under Google's two factor authentication.

Otherwise I figure they were for one time use and you can just keep cranking out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to retrieve application-specific passwords. They are - indeed - for one-time-use - I was not able to use the same password on more than one app without getting a password invalid message. The number of application specific passwords is unlimited.

Comment: This was also much conclusion.  Just checking all the bases.